# mapStateToProps' State Argument is a Dispatch Function and Not Store Data

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I am trying to wire up redux with reactjs to store some information about a component clicked on. After clicking on a certain component the redux store is updated and I wanted it to check the store before rendering for the next page. I can confirm that the state is updated with the data but when I use mapStateToProps the state is a dispatch function and not data?

ConnectedRequestInformation.js container

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import requestInformationComponent from "../components/pages/pipeline/requestInformation";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {typeOfRequest: state.typeOfRequest}
}

export default connect(
  () => ({}),
  mapStateToProps
)(requestInformationComponent);
```

RequestInformationComponent

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
import DynamicFormComponent from "../../helpers/DynamicForm"

export const requestInformation = (typeOfRequest) => (
  <div>
  <DynamicFormComponent requestType={typeOfRequest}/>
  </div>
);
export default requestInformation
```

The console log from the container prints this out.

```
    function dispatch(action) {
        if (!isPlainObject(action)) {
          throw new Error('Actions must be plain objects. ' + 'Use custom middleware for async actions.');
        }

        if (typeof action.type === 'undefined') {
          throw new Error('Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. ' + 'Have y

ou misspelled a constant?');
    }

    if (isDispatching) {
      throw new Error('Reducers may not dispatch actions.');
    }

    try {
      isDispatching = true;
      currentState = currentReducer(currentState, action);
    } finally {
      isDispatching = false;
    }

    var listeners = currentListeners = nextListeners;
    for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
      var listener = listeners[i];
      listener();
    }

    return action;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your following code:

```
export default connect(
  () => ({}),
  mapStateToProps
)(requestInformationComponent);
```

should be

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(requestInformationComponent);`

so `mapStateToProps` should be the first argument to the connect function.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Why did the code I have not work?

Comment: its because you passed `mapStateToProps` as second argument to `connect` (thats incorrect). the second argument is for `mapDispatchToProps`.